# error: 'did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I am trying to push files into git repo.
I have created some new folders files etc.
I am using IDEA to do a commit. However when i try to commit it complains about:

> error: pathspec 'path/to/file'
>   did not match any file(s) known to git.

For every file. I have created a new branch ( the branch is indeed present on git ) and checkouted it. I tried everything i have found about this problem, git reset, pulling fetching an so on, nothing helps.

Is there some way how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

IDEA uses some complex logic to keep the state of your index when committing - (save index state - commit what it needs - restore the index as it used to be, when possible), and the error might be a result of restoring the index. Hard to tell without additional info.

I believe it is worth [submitting a ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) to JetBrains, with logs attached.